# In my App memory graph, there are instances of dispatch_group leaked but I don't use that technology explicitly. Any possible suggestion?

Tags: cocoa, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch

In my macOS App with Mixed Objective-C/Swift, in the Xcode memory graph, there are instances of dispatch_group leaked:

[image: picture_of_xcode_memory_graph]

I am a bit familiar with GCD and I use it in my project, but I don't use dispatch_groups explicitly in my code. I have thought that it could be some indirect usage of it when I call other GCD APIs like dispatch_async. I was wondering if there is somebody that can help me track this issue. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose this, you want to know (a) what is keeping a strong reference to them; and (b) where these objects were instantiated. Unfortunately, unlike many objects, dispatch groups might not tell you much about the former (though your memory addresses suggest that there might be some object keeping a reference to them), but we can use the “Malloc Stack” feature to answer the latter.

So, edit your scheme (“Product” » “Scheme” » “Edit Scheme” or press <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd><</kbd>) and temporarily turn on this feature:

[image]

You can then click on the object in question and the panel on the right might show you illuminating stack information about where the object was allocated:

[image]

Now, in this case, in `viewDidLoad` I manually instantiated six dispatch groups, performed an `enter`, but not a `leave`, which is why these objects are still in memory. This is a common source of dispatch groups lingering in memory.

As you look at the stack trace, focus first on entries in your codebase (in white, rather than gray, in the stack trace). And if you click on your code in the stack trace, it will even jump you to the relevant line of code. But even if it is not in your code, often the stack trace will give you insights where these dispatch groups were created, and you can start your research there.

And remember, when you are done with your diagnostics, make sure to turn off the “Malloc Stack” feature.